# How do I limit head rotation in Unity3D Google Cardboard?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am having trouble limiting rotation. I have added this Script to both the Cardboard Main object, Head object, and Main Camera object, with no success.  Here is what I have so far, and it doesn't stop the rotation.

```
void FixedUpdate () {

    if (transform.eulerAngles.y > 60 && transform.eulerAngles.y < 190)
    {

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, 60, transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }

    if (transform.eulerAngles.y > 190 && transform.eulerAngles.y < 300)
    {

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, 300, transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The google cardboard SDK has code setting the heads orientation each frame. Even if you set yours, their will override it when it is executed. If you want to tweak head movement, do so by modifying the Cardboard scripts.

Also, you shouldn't do such things. Forcing some camera movement on the users in a VR app is an easy way to make them disoriented or nauseous. What are you trying to achieve by limiting the possible orientation of the head?

Comment: The reason I need to limit head orientation is because the enemies are only coming from one direction.

Comment: This reason is not good enough. If the player wants to turn his back on the enemies, let him. If you are worried he wont know where to look for them, put a wall right behind him. That way he can look around freely, and knows where to look for enemies.

Comment: Ok thanks I wont limit the rotation. Another question now though, how do  I get the direction the device is facing? Say north, south, east, or west along the x and y axis?

Comment: @danielmetlitski ask that as a separate question :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046425/how-can-i-find-the-rotation-of-the-head-in-google-cardboard-unity3d

Answer (score 0):

In CardboardHead.cs, under UpdateHead() add this below `bool updateEarly`:

```
public float limit = 0.5f;
```

then change:

```
transform.localRotation = rot;
```

to:

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rot, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward), limit);
```

This will give you a limit parameter on the head object that you can use to limit the sensitivity of the Cardboard's rotation.