# How can I find the rotation of the head in Google Cardboard Unity3D?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Hey guys how do I find the rotation of the phone with Google Cardboard SDK in Unity3D, like the way the persons head is facing? I need to find if it is facing more towards the east, the west, or the north. Do I find the rotation of the head, or the parent Main camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cardboard class contains a property called HeadRotation which is a Quaternion.

```
Quaternion crtRot = youCardboardController.HeadRotation;
```

To use its rotation like you'd in Unity with directional vectors you may simply multiply it by Vector3.forward.

```
Vector3 lookDir = crtRot * Vector3.forward;
```

Visualizing the vector in editor might help narrow down issues

```
void Update () {
  // ..
  Debug.DrawRay( pos, lookDir * 100, Color.blue );
  // ..
}
```

From here you only need to know where North is, in meaning of the facing vector. Do a Vector3.Angle() and you have the angle between your avatar's and North's vector. You might want to evaluate both vectors with their y axes set to 0.

You could also use Vector3.Dot() (the dot product) to determine how much both vectors look into the same direction.

I had an issue with HeadPosition, which wasn't updated properly. So if you operate from HeadPosition keep in mind it may stick to 0,0,0 .

Answer (score 0):

Take `Head.transform.rotation` - that's the orientation of the user's head.

I'm not really sure what do you mean by North or West. If the mobile device has a magnetometer, then maybe you could read it's data to determine where North is, but I've never done that

Comment: The Main Camera gameobject and Head gameobject don't reflect the rotation ingame.
What object is actually being rotated when he head is turning?

Comment: How do they "not reflect the rotation"? Have you set up everything properly? Do the cameras properly react to head/phone movement?

Comment: its the "Head" object that does it, not the Main Camera

Answer (score 0):

It would be the rotation of the Head object, although the Main Camera usually has the same rotation.

But if you want the direction relative to the real world, that information is not available in the SDK.  The compass cannot be used because of the magnet, so there is no way to get the real direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the **rotation angle of the main camera** in the scene. It will gives you the head rotation angles with respect to x, y and z axis.

In GVR based VR scenes the system is internally rotating the camera with respect to our head movements. So it's easy to get the head rotation using main camera rotation angles.

For that,

```
//local rotation of the Transform of the camera
Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.y

//The world Y rotation
Camera.main.transform.rotation.y
```